# Unable to source name out of some content using xpath

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I've written a very simple xpath to parse the name out of some content but it is neither working nor throwing any error. It seemed to me that I did nothing wrong. Can somebody tell me why the below xpath expression is not working? Thanks for any input.

I tried like this:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

content='''
    <Traveller>
        <name>John</name>
        <passnum>572014</passnum>
        <addr>Florida</addr>
    </Traveller>
    <Traveller>
        <name>Craig</name>
        <passnum>516114</passnum>
        <addr>Boston</addr>
    </Traveller>
'''
root = fromstring(content)
for item in root.xpath("//Traveller/name/text()"):
    print(item)
```

Expected output:

```
John
Craig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the document after it parsed by `lxml.html`, you'll see that all the element names turned to lower-case, that's why your attempted xpath didn't work :

```
....
>>> from lxml import html
>>> html.tostring(root)
'<span><traveller>\n        <name>John</name>\n        <passnum>572014</passnum>\n        <addr>Florida</addr>\n    </traveller>\n    <traveller>\n        <name>Craig</name>\n        <passnum>516114</passnum>\n        <addr>Boston</addr>\n    </traveller>\n</span>'
```

and using lower-case works :

```
>>> for item in root.xpath("//traveller/name/text()"):
...     print(item)
... 
John
Craig
```

Comment: Yes yes yes!!!! This is it. I almost went mad finding out what I was doing wrong. So this the `case` issue. Thanks har07, for your answer and the clarity..

Answer (score 1):

A proper/valid xml/html document should always contain the ***root*** tag/node i.e. the main parent tag comprising all remaining nodes.

The proper approach should look like:

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring

content='''
<travels>
    <Traveller>
        <name>John</name>
        <passnum>572014</passnum>
        <addr>Florida</addr>
    </Traveller>
    <Traveller>
        <name>Craig</name>
        <passnum>516114</passnum>
        <addr>Boston</addr>
    </Traveller>
</travels>
'''
root = fromstring(content)
for item in root.xpath("//Traveller/name/text()"):
    print(item)
```

The output:

```
John
Craig
```

Comment: Thanks RomanPerekhrest, for your answer. It works as well. Too many fruitful answers. +1 for this.